# Design a simulink logic that can give a square wave which is high for two samples and low for two samples. generate code for the logic

Tags: matlab, model, logic, delay, simulink

Design a simulink logic that can give a square wave which is high for two samples and low for two samples. Generate code for the logic.

I don't have an idea how to do it. I am aware of doing it using pulse generator. But in this question it is not recommended to use pulse generator.